# Handling date from list of times

Tags: python

I have a list of time.

```
time_list = ['7pm', '8pm', '9pm', '10pm', '11pm', '12am', '1am', '2am']
```

and from there a list of floats as well

```
fl_list = ['1.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '11', '12.0']
```

Upon inserting in the database,
I set the date of time 7pm-12am to date today, and 1am-2am to date tomorrow.

```py
date_today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
date_tomorrow = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

My code is like this:

```py
has_tomorrow_record = all(any(x in y for y in time_list) for x in ["12am", "1am"])
```

then to get the date I have to do the below condition

```py
for t in time_list:
    if has_tomorrow_record and "am" in t:
        if t != "12am":
            date = date_tomorrow
```

Is there a cleaner way to determine the dates for the time_list?

Comment: do you mean: `if t in ["12am", "1am"]: date = date_tomorrow`?

Comment: How does `fl_list` play into this?

Comment: @wjandrea its the data associated with the time_list

Comment: @Masoud isnt 12am considered as date_today and 1am as date_tomorrow?

Comment: if t is a list, use this: `if any(hour in ['1am', '2am'] for hour in t): date=date_tomorrow`. if t is a string, for example '1am', try this: `if t in ['1am', '2am']: date=date_tomorrow`

Comment: @Masoud `t` is a string for example `1am`

Comment: Please post your expected output